# PdfBox fails to import page

Tags: pdfbox

I have the following code

```
0. templatePage = (PDPage) PDDocument.load(file).getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
1. ...
2. document.importPage(templatePage); //first page
3. ... //draw stuff
4. document.importPage(templatePage); //next page
5. ...
```

If at line 3 I draw only a few stuff, then everything works fine. However if I draw a lot of stuff, then I get:

```
Index: 12, Size: 0. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:84)
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileInputStream.read(RandomAccessFileInputStream.java:96)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.importPage(PDDocument.java:654)
at xxx.PdfReport.breakPage(PdfReport.java:145)
at xxx.PdfReport.print(PdfReport.java:84)
```

The above code work in 95% of cases, problems appears only when the page is really full.

If at line 2. & 4. I use

```
 document.addPage(new PDPage());
```

then it works fine. But the goal is to use a template pdf.

Answer (score 0):

A hacked solution is:

Load the template every time before using it. Make sure that the template document is not GCd.
Then it will work.

If anyone has an official solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### The main issue

The main issue is that you load a `PDDocument` from file,

```
PDDocument.load(file)
```

extract a `PDPage`  object from it,

```
....getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0)
```

but don't hold onto the `PDDocument` instance anymore when using the page.

```
document.importPage(templatePage)
```

Thus, you allow garbage collection to claim the `PDDocument` instance pulling the carpet from under the `PDPage` instance:

A `PDPage` object does *not* hold all the information on all the page contents but merely some object identifiers which have to be resolved during a `document.importPage` call; if the source `PDDocument` has meanwhile been finalized (due to not being referenced and, therefore, eventually being processed by garbage collection), they cannot be resolved anymore.

Symptoms of this may differ, in my tests I got no exception but instead a SEVERE log output

```
No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
```

and either no page was imported or the imported page was missing some resources, e.g. embedded fonts.

(BTW, I actually would *prefer* to get an exception here because without it the code assumes it *successfully imported the page*)

### The solution

Hold on to the `PDDocument` instance as long as you use it:

```
0. PDDocument sourceDocument = PDDocument.load(file);
   templatePage = (PDPage) sourceDocument .getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
1. ...
2. document.importPage(templatePage); //first page
3. ... //draw stuff
4. document.importPage(templatePage); //next page
5. ...
   sourceDocument.close();
```

The final `sourceDocument.close` call frees resources at a time of your choice, not at a time governed by garbage collection.

### Other optimizations

A problem with importing the same template `PDPage` twice is that the same content stream is twice in the result file, and probably its resources, too. Depending on the nature of the page in question, this may mean quite a lot of overhead. You can get around this overhead by importing the template page once as a form xobject and including a reference to this xobject on as many pages in the target document as you want.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265) to [How to insert an PDPage within another PDPage with pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26256546/1729265) explains how to import a template page as a form xobject and put it onto some target page in the current PDFBox 2.0.0 development SNAPSHOT. Something analogous should be possible for the current release versions 1.8.X, too.